# Would you add capacitors to a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, voltage-divider

[image]

Would you add capacitors to a voltage divider?

I'm feeding this voltage into 4 comparators.

Would it add stability to the voltage, or is it not necessary at all?

Comment: You can. It forms an RC lowpass filter. Fluctuations on the +12V voltage or the output voltage (due to current draw) will be smoothed out.

Comment: It depends. Is the 12V noisy? Which comparators are used? Does the circuit have hysteresis?

Comment: *Would you add capacitors to a voltage divider?* Yes I would, since the output voltage is a DC voltage so adding decoupling capacitors is almost always a good idea. Realize that you can always just make the provisions for the capacitors but not place them on the PCB if it turns out that having them or not makes no difference in measurements.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Thanks, that was the idea, add the footprints and see how it turns out, just wanted to know how other people think about it. for a single device i wouldn't, but now I'm feeding it into 4.

Comment: @NaturalDemon without context, what would it help what other people do in other contextes? You need to be aware of what you're doing with the voltage and how stable your ground and supply voltage are, relative to that desired output.

Comment: what? Sorry, none of this makes sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller all the modules i make are proper decoupled, they should not be influenced by others.

Comment: You wouldn't add capacitors to a signal voltage divider unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason.

Comment: @Andyaka, well the idea was to stabilize the voltage divider if you have multiple devices depending on it.

Comment: @NaturalDemon yes but which devices? You say comparators. We don't know what your comparators do in the circuit and which comparators they are. Should we assume the comparators are digital or analog, integrated circuits or vacuum tubes?

Comment: @Justme plain LM339'ers pulling a FET high or low.

Comment: @NaturalDemon for which purpose, which intended bandwidth, with how much noise on power and ground? I feel like I might be repeating myself, but the *application context*, i.e. *why* you have this define *what* it needs to do, which in turn decides *how* you build it – and thus the need for capacitors.

Comment: Two downvotes for a good question. Yes you can and often should filter. Usually 10nF are enough for most purpose, no need for electrolytics (depend on what you are doing with the output)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio, just wanted to know people's opinion on this subject, in many schematics i have seen it's never used. thank you for the 10nF value recommendation. you don't use the formulas day in and out, so they slip away overtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAUfot.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The schematic above shows the original and the Thevenin equivalent of your divider.

> I'm feeding this voltage into 4 comparators.

If you use this voltage as a reference then it sure is better to get it as clean and stable as possible. So, adding a capacitor, as can be seen from the circuit at right-hand side more clearly, will turn the divider circuit into a divider + low-pass filter combo which helps to reduce the noise on the supply line.

On the other hand, however, increasing the capacitance for stability will lead to a long rise-time for the output of the divider, and this might not be a requirement for your application. So you need to be careful on this.

Comment: Thanks, ya, but once the caps are full they should stay there, that's faster than you're playing the intrument, I'll add the footprints for a 100nF and 1uF and populate them if needed.